# Unattended upgrades on Ubuntu, for *all* packages (from any repository)

Tags: ubuntu, cron, apt, unattended

I'd like to have my Ubuntu system automatically upgrade all packages. I added to my `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`:

```
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

However, I still need to maintain the list of Allowed-Origins in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`. Is there any way to simply allow all origins?

Another more serious problem than having to maintain the origins list is the bug that [origins can't contain spaces](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=536754).  This is fixed in the latest unattended-upgrades, but that's not in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (which we're sticking to for a while).

I also know about cron-apt, but I heard it hangs if there are prompts during the upgrade, e.g. for config file conflicts (this is also the problem with `aptitude full-upgrade` cron scripts), whereas unattended-upgrades can detect this and not proceed.  Is there anything else out there that is behaved like unattended-upgrades but doesn't require maintenance of an Allowed-Origins list?

Note: I'm aware of the arguments against unattended upgrades. Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

I used to create a bash script like this to accomplish this task - then just call it from cron:

```
#!/usr/bin/env 
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -qq
```

Honestly, I used -d -q (download only), to download the updates onto my staging server in the middle of the night. I'd then test them when I got in to the office, and push them to our internal apt-proxy server.

Comment: I had actually been trying this approach (simple cron script calling `aptitude full-upgrade -y`) for lack of other options. I initially was resistant to this because of what I mentioned in my question - potential problems arising from things like file conflicts.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I pulled it to a staging server, and the moved the packages over to a internal apt-proxy server when I had tested. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for an automated way for all repos: https://github.com/abhigenie92/unattended_upgrades_repos